# Replace value with item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'm really not sure how to explain what i'm trying to achieve, but what is the easiest way to do something like this (in javascript):

```
function switchItUp(i){
    ...
}

old_values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
new_values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

switchItUp(3); // returns "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function switchItUp(i) {
    return new_values[old_values.indexOf(i)];
}
```

Keep in mind that the indexOf function does not work in IE8 and earlier. If you want support in those browsers, you may want to try jQuery's [inArray function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) or Underscore.js's [indexOf function](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf).

Comment: Works... depending on the browser. indexOf for arrays has limited support.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through first array until value is found, use looping variable to index into second array:

```
function switchItUp(i) {
    var j, l = old_values.length;
    for (j = 0; j < l; j += 1) {
        if (old_values[j] === i) {
            return new_values[j];
        }
    }
}
```